# Помогите с отправкой форм на сервер через jquery, ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

При первом клике форма отправляется. А при втором только скрывается. Но не отправляются данные. Нужно свести все это к одному клику ***`Форма прячется, данные отправляются.`***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var close = $('#close2');
  var form = $('.form');
  var success_message = $('.none');
  $('body').on('submit', '#offer-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'mail.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        close.on('click', function() {
          form.hide(500);
          $('form :input').val('');
          success_message.show(500);
          setTimeout(function() {
            form.show(500);
            success_message.hide(500);
          }, 3000)
        });
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="offer-form" class="form offer_form">
  <input type="text" name="username" class="input offer__input" placeholder="Ваше имя" />
  <input type="tel" name="userphone" class="input offer__input" placeholder="Ваш телефон" />
  <button id="close2" class="btn offer__button">
                  Получить бесплатный дизайн-проект
          </button>
</form>
<div class="none" class="success-support">Спасибо за заявку, скоро мы вам перезвоним.</div>
<!-- /.form offer_form -->
<div class="success"></div>
<div class="info">
  <span class="info__support">Наш менеджер перезвонит Вам<br/>в течение 60 секунд</span>
  <span class="info__support">или перезвоните нам сами <b><br/>+7 (495) 42-251-31</b></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $('body').on('submit', '#offer-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'mail.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        //close.on('click', function () {
          form.hide(500);
          $('form :input').val('');
          success_message.show(500);
          setTimeout(function () {
            form.show(500);
            success_message.hide(500);
          }, 3000)
        //});
      }
```

Comment: так не работает

Comment: @Артем Что значит  "не работает"?